# How to sum cardView item values in recyclerView and display the total sum on a textView outside the recyclerView

Tags: android

I am working on restaurant app wants to display selected items for order, with their price per item and total price (count*price) of each item. I want to add those total price of list of card items and display on text view outside Recycler View that will change dynamically.

Inside each card View, there are two buttons(- and +) that change the count value for each item so that it changes the total price of each item.

Here is My adapter class

```
public class MyListsToOrderAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListsToOrderAdapter.MyHOldd>{

ArrayList<Element> element;
Context ctx;
TextView textView;
String c;
String db = "Elements";
String dbp = "Prices";
PriceDao priceDao;
ElementDao elementDao;
int count=0;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
float v1,v4,v5,v2,v3,v6;
float x1,x2,x3=0;

public MyListsToOrderAdapter( ArrayList<Element> element,Context ctx,TextView textView) {

    this.textView=textView;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.element = element;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);


}

@Override
public MyListsToOrderAdapter.MyHOldd onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_lists_to_order,parent,false);
    MyHOldd holder = new MyHOldd(view,ctx,element);

    return holder;

}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyListsToOrderAdapter.MyHOldd holder, final int position) {

      priceDao=setUpDBPrice();
  String bs=  element.get(position).getCode();
List<Price> priceList = priceDao.queryBuilder().where(PriceDao.Properties.ElCode.eq(bs)).list();
    String pricev = priceList.get(0).getPriceValue();
      // Calculating the total price of each
    v1 = Float.parseFloat(pricev);
    v2= Float.parseFloat(element.get(position).getCount());
    v3=v1*v2;

    final String res = String.valueOf(v3);

    holder.listName.setText(element.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.add.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
    holder.sub.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
    holder.pricess.setText(pricev);
    holder.totalPriceT.setText(res);
    holder.status.setText(element.get(position).getCount());

         if(v5==1)v5=v6;
         else if(v5==2) v5=-v6;
          else if(v5==3) v5=0;
         else  v5=v3;
    v4=v4+v5;

    String ch = String.valueOf(v4);
    textView.setText("Total: "+ch);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return element.size();
}

 class MyHOldd extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

     public TextView listName;
     public TextView pricess;
     public  TextView status;
     public TextView totalPriceT;
     public ImageView add;
     public ImageView sub;
     int count;

     Context ctx;
     ArrayList<Element> element = new ArrayList<>();
      ElementDao elementDao = setupDbElement();

     public MyHOldd(View itemView, Context ctx, ArrayList<Element> element) {
         super(itemView);
         this.ctx=ctx;
         this.element=element;

         listName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TitemName);
         pricess = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TitemPrice);
         status = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Tstatus);
         totalPriceT = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);
         add = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TplusSign);
         sub = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TminusSign);
         add.setOnClickListener(this);
         sub.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         int position = getAdapterPosition();
         Element element = this.element.get(position);
         String bd=  element.getCode();
         List<Price> priceList = priceDao.queryBuilder().where(PriceDao.Properties.ElCode.eq(bd)).list();
         String pricev = priceList.get(0).getPriceValue();
         // Calculating the total price of each
         v6 = Float.parseFloat(pricev);
         x3=v6*count;
             v5=0;
         count= Integer.parseInt(element.getCount());
         if(view.getId()==add.getId()) {
             count = count+1;
             c = String.valueOf(count);
             element.setCount(c);
             elementDao.update(element);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             v5=1;
         } else if (view.getId()==sub.getId()) {
             if(count==0) {
                 count = 0;
                 c = String.valueOf(count);
                 element.setCount(c);
                 elementDao.update(element);
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                 v5=3;
             }
             else {
                 count = count-1;
                 c = String.valueOf(count);
                 element.setCount(c);
                 elementDao.update(element);
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                 v5=2;
             }
         }
         count= Integer.parseInt(element.getCount());

     }
 }
```

Comment: i am new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works like this for me, I changed notifyDataSetChanged(); into notifyItemChanged(position);

so that I can get the total value (v4) and pass it to text view as shown

```
  @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     int position = getAdapterPosition();
     Element element = this.element.get(position);
     String bd=  element.getCode();
     List<Price> priceList = priceDao.queryBuilder().where(PriceDao.Properties.ElCode.eq(bd)).list();
     String pricev = priceList.get(0).getPriceValue();
     // Calculating the total price of each
     v6 = Float.parseFloat(pricev);
     x3=v6*count;
         v5=0;
     count= Integer.parseInt(element.getCount());
     if(view.getId()==add.getId()) {
         count = count+1;
         c = String.valueOf(count);
         element.setCount(c);
         elementDao.update(element);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
         v5=1;
     } else if (view.getId()==sub.getId()) {
         if(count==0) {
             count = 0;
             c = String.valueOf(count);
             element.setCount(c);
             elementDao.update(element);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             v5=3;
         }
         else {
             count = count-1;
             c = String.valueOf(count);
             element.setCount(c);
             elementDao.update(element);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             v5=2;
         }
     }
     count= Integer.parseInt(element.getCount());

 }
```

}
///////////////////////////////
so that I can get the total value (v4) and pass it to text view as shown

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyListsToOrderAdapter.MyHOldd holder, final int position) {
      priceDao=setUpDBPrice();
  String bs=  element.get(position).getCode();
List<Price> priceList = priceDao.queryBuilder().where(PriceDao.Properties.ElCode.eq(bs)).list();
    String pricev = priceList.get(0).getPriceValue();

      // Calculating the total price of each

    v1 = Float.parseFloat(pricev);
    v2= Float.parseFloat(element.get(position).getCount());
    v3=v1*v2;

    final String res = String.valueOf(v3);

    holder.listName.setText(element.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.add.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
    holder.sub.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
    holder.pricess.setText(pricev);
    holder.totalPriceT.setText(res);
    holder.status.setText(element.get(position).getCount());
    holder.addNote.setText("Add");
```

// Calculating the Total price of all items

```
        if(v5==1)v5=v6;
         else if(v5==3) v5=-v6;
          else if(v5==2) v5=0;
        else  v5=v3;
          v4=v4+v5;
```

// displayin on the textView

```
    String ch = String.valueOf(v4);
    textView.setText("Total: "+ch);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Habatamu 
Everytime you click add or sub imageview the textview for totalSum should be updated. In your case, the override method onclick does not seems to be updating the  totalSum.

Comment: it does update the total sum but it brings the wrong answer in the all total sum that displayed on textView. but once I refresh the page it displays the right answer on textView.

Comment: Seems like you have the data redundancy issue. I hope you are using your recyclerview viewholder in better way that does not lead to the repetition of same data twice basically upon scroll.